# Is it possible to pass object arguments backwards?

Tags: python

I have two object classes: `class Hero(object):` and `class Alien(object)` each with a `name` parameter that contains the name of the object instance. In each class I have a class method called `def die(self):` which defines what happens when the Hero is hit or not hit. While I am able to reference the object inside itself, I'm having trouble doing the backwards operation, which is referencing the object that references the method. Sorry if this is confusing, here is what I mean:

```
#this die and blast function is contained in both classes
def die(self):    
    #(pseudocode) if hit:
        print (self.name, " is hit!")
    #(pseudocode) elif not hit:
        print (enemy.name, " misses!") #<-- currently doesn't work because enemy is not defined in the die function
def blast(self, enemy):
    print(self.name," blasts ", enemy.name, "\n")
    enemy.die()

def main():
    heroObject = Hero()
    alienObject = Alien()
    heroObject.blast(alienObject)
```

Here's my question: I know that when I call `blast()` that I use the name of the object as the argument. But inside of the `blast()` and `die()` functions, how can I call the name of the object that originally called it? The line `print (enemy.name, " misses!")` doesn't currently work because `enemy` is not defined in the `die` function. Ideally what would happen is the name of the enemy would appear in the `print` statement.

Comment: Do you just need `def die(self, enemy):`?

Comment: Off topic, but you may want to consider creating something like a `Fighter` or `Character` class as a base class and inheriting your different character classes from that. This would allow you to avoid repeating the code for `blast`, `die`, etc.

Comment: You're totally right and I was thinking that as I was constantly duplicating code. I think this will be covered in my next hw assignment :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the other object from `die()`, pass it into the function explicitly:

```
def die(self, enemy):    
    #(pseudocode) if hit:
        print (self.name, " is hit!")
    #(pseudocode) elif not hit:
        print (enemy.name, " misses!")

def blast(self, enemy):
    print(self.name," blasts ", enemy.name, "\n")
    enemy.die(self)

def main():
    heroObject = Hero()
    alienObject = Alien()
    heroObject.blast(alienObject)
```

Notice how the meaning of `self` and `enemy` is reversed when we go from `blast()` into `die()`.

One observation, if I may, is that it seems a bit odd to have the "if misses" logic inside `die()`. It seems to imply that `die()` could be called even if the enemy hasn't died and isn't about to die. I think that logic belongs outside the function.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Python noobs like me need all the help they can get.